# Are there any strings that break `s1.equalsIgnoreCase(s2) == (s1.toLowerCase(Locale.US) == s2.toLowerCase(Locale.US))`

Tags: java, scala, case-insensitive

I'm trying to address a hypothetical concern brought up by a coworker, regarding case-insensitive comparisons versus using `toLowerCase`.

Wherever possible, we try to use `equalsIgnoreCase` (or whatever the specific language / environment provides) for case-insensitive string comparisons. But in some cases, we have to compute a hash of the string and compare hashes. We use `hash(s.toLowerCase(Locale.US))` to avoid failing [the Turkey Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796986/what-is-the-turkey-test), but still there is some concern that there could exist a pair of strings for which

```
s1.equalsIgnoreCase(s2) != (s1.toLowerCase(Locale.US) == s2.toLowerCase(Locale.US))
```

i.e. the case-insensitive comparison says one thing, but the locale-specified lowercase comparison says something else.

If such a pair existed, a comparison of hashes generated by `sha(s.toLowerCase(Locale.US))` could tell us that the two strings aren't equal when in fact they are.

**Does a pair of strings (s1, s2) exist which satisfies the expression above?**

---

*Follow-up edit in lieu of answering my own question, since I accepted a linked answer that was provided in the comments.*

One example is the pair of strings, `("ϑ", "ϴ")` (Theta, and "Small Theta"). Both are considered equal by `equalsIgnoreCase`, but neither are modified by `.toLowerCase(Locale.US)`

This hits the edge-case [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25513019/string-equalsignorecase-uppercase-v-lowercase)

```scala
import java.util.Locale
def lower(s: String) = s.toLowerCase(Locale.US)
def upper(s: String) = s.toUpperCase(Locale.US)

val s1 = "ϑ"
val s2 = "ϴ"
println(s"CI Equals: ${s1 equalsIgnoreCase s2}") // true
println(s"Lower Equals: ${lower(s1) == lower(s2)}") // false
println(s"UpperLower Equals: ${lower(upper(s1)) == lower(upper(s2))}") // true
```

To quote the linked answer,

> a true case insensitive comparison [...] must check the lowercases of the uppercases.

Comment: This question shouldn't be "language agnostic" because the implementation of `equalsIgnoreCase` and `toLowerCase` depends on the language.

Comment: @Dialecticus For the purposes of this question, assume the two functions are "correct" to the greatest possible extent. E.g. `equalsIgnoreCase` is a true case-insensitive equality check, and `toLowerCase(US)` performs a lowercase conversion the way an American would. I expressed them in terms of the language I happen to be using, but my intent is to find a programming-language-agnostic answer.

Comment: That said, I'm curious now as to how different programming languages would provide different behavior for a locale-specified `toLowerCase` function. Any examples?

Comment: I understood that you have an actual project written in an actual language, and a possible problem in your actual project. It is counterproductive to look for hypothetical language-agnostic solutions if the problem is constrained to actual language. Why do you insist on language agnostic, if you project is written in java? Makes no sense.

Comment: Java users may answer with "ah yes, I know about this problem, and here's how I have solved it". But Java users may not find your question, because it is not tagged with java tag.

Comment: Did you mean `equals` instead of the second `==` in the title?

Comment: That depends on how `equalsIgnoreCase` is implemented, no?

Comment: @MadPhysicist For a Java reader, yes. I'm using Scala so `==` and `equals` are the same thing, but someone edited the tags to remove the scala tag

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60196641/2988730

Comment: @MadPhysicist I accepted your linked question as a duplicate since it gave me enough information to answer my question; I've edited my question to include that info in lieu of adding an answer

Comment: ...maybe I should've just added an answer, since that apparently was a confusing thing to do.